# Open Dynamically generated pdf as html page

Tags: java, hibernate, pdf, struts2

I am working on web development project
IDE used:Eclipse
Language:JAVA(framework used:hibernate,struts2)

I have created a pdf file using java and I want to view that dynamically created pdf as a html page.

Here is my code

```
    public String SOSViewFile()
{

    try {
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        PDFGenerator pdf = new PDFGenerator();

        PDFGenerator generator=new PDFGenerator();


    /*    byte[] bytes = null;
        bytes = (generator.generatepdf(sosValues.getCmaId(), null)).toByteArray();

        //bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

        if (bytes != null) {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        }*/

        baos=generator.generatepdf(sosValues.getCmaId(), null);
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

        PdfReader pdfReader=new PdfReader(bis);

        PdfStamper pdfStamper=new PdfStamper(pdfReader, baos);
        pdfStamper.setEncryption(null, null, PdfWriter.HideToolbar, PdfWriter.STRENGTH40BITS);
        pdfStamper.close();
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());



        ///baos.close();






    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    return SUCCESS;
}
```

bis and baos are

```
private InputStream bis;
private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
```

Please help me in converting this generated pdf file to a html.

Answer (score 0):

Write the generated bytes to the servlet response's `OutputStream` and set the mime-type to application/pdf.

It won't convert it to HTML (of course), but many browsers will open it directly (YMMV).

Comment: *Every* browser (with a suitable plugin installed) will open it directly, because of ContentDisposition HTTP header default value is `inline`

Comment: I already have done it.It is opening as pdf attachment but I want it to be html page(open pdf as html)

Comment: @jeetZ Well, if Andrea is correct (which I don't doubt), it's your browser's fault. What are you opening it with? Also, your code seems to be missing a lot of things, for example what headers you're setting.

Answer (score 0):

The tool that might help you is [CSSBox/pdf2dom](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/). It converts pdf to html page.